# How do I check if at least one child's attribute contains a specific word in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt

I actually have to make an xsl file for an xml about recipes. I have to show only the recipes made with a particular ingredient. The xml file looks like this:

```
<recipe name="A">
    <ingrediente name="B"></ingredient>
    <ingrediente name="C"></ingredient>
</recipe>
```

I do something like this:

```
<xsl:for-each select="recipe">
    <xsl:if test="contains(ingredient/@name,'C')">
        Shows the recipe
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I have a problem because when I try to know if at least one of the ingredientes have a particular name it just cheks the first ingredient. In that example the recipe "A" has the ingrediente "C", but it won't be shown because it just checks the first ingrediente, which is "B". If "C" is the first ingredient, the recipe is shown.

Any idea how to do this work? (and sorry if my english is not very good)

Comment: `ingrediente` or `ingredient`? Your XML is not well formed.  Please don't retype code, use copy/paste to avoid introducing typos.

Comment: Why don’t you just search for recipe/ingredient[@name=‘C’] in your select query at the start and do away with the if clause? I can’t test my proposal as I am not at home so it might not be 100% right.

Comment: If it's only considering the first element, rather than reporting an error, this means you are using XPath 1.0 rather than a later version. Since this is obviously an academic exercise, why are you using an obsolete version of the language?

Comment: @MichaelKay I don't want to go off topic but you refer to XPath 1.0 as obsolete. I assume that relates to XSLT-1? If so, this is the only transformation that my PC seems to support natively with the browser. I know I can program using a newer transformation technology etc. but not when I want to use Internet Explorer to open the XSL/XML transformation. So for me, it is not obsolete, it is the only thing available. Unless I get it wrong?

Comment: Yes, it's the only thing that comes "out of the box" with the browsers, or with the JDK, or with .NET. But you're not restricted to technology that comes free with your computer. And my main point was really, if you are constrained to use very old technology for some reason, you should say so in your post.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do only a slight change in your script.

The idea is:

- Take a `recipe` to check.
- Go "down" to each `ingredient`...
- and check (in a predicate) whether **any** its attribute (`@*`)...
- contains particular string.
- Then go up one level (`/..`) and return the current (`recipe`) element
  for further processing.

So the `for-each` loop should look like below:

```
<xsl:for-each select="recipe/ingredient[contains(@*,'C')]/..">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Note that it is possible to check that **any** attribute contains the specified string, just as you wrote in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<xsl:for-each select="recipe">
    <xsl:if test="contains(ingredient/@name,'C')">
        Shows the recipe
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

to

```
<xsl:for-each select="recipe[ingredient/@name='C']">
    Shows the recipe
</xsl:for-each>
```

So that the iteration is specifically defined over *only the targeted* `recipes`.  Note also that you should not use `contains()` here or you'll also match `Carrots` and `Corn`.